# Find the flux integral of the vector field $F=(0,0,-1)$ through the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surface-integrals, fluid-dynamics

> A uniform fluid flowing vertically downward (heavy rain) is described by the vector field $F=(0,0,-1)$. Find the total flow through the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.

> b)Now consider $F=(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0,\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2})$ and Find the total flow through the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

**Attempt a)**
We shall use the expresion
$$\int {F dS}=\int \int_{D}F \cdot ( T_{u} \times T_{v})=\int \int_D (-Pg_x-Qg_y+R)dA$$
Notice that the region $S$ alredy was given $g(x,y)=z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$$g_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$g_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
doing the substitution on the integral
$$\iint_{D}(-0g_x-0g_y+(-1))dA$$

Since $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ we shall use polar cordinates

$$x=r \cos \theta $$
$$y=r \sin \theta$$
where $r\in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$
Finally doing the integration
$$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1}-rdrd \theta=-\pi $$

> Now for $b)

We shall use the expresion
$$\int {F dS}=\int \int_{D}F \cdot ( T_{u} \times T_{v})=\int \int_D (-Pg_x-Qg_y+R)dA$$
Notice that the region $S$ alredy was given $g(x,y)=z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$$g_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$g_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
doing the substitution on the integral
$$\iint_{D}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}g_x-0g_y+(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}))dA$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \iint_{D}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1)dA$$
Usinng polar coordinates we get
$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} (cos \theta-1)r dr d\theta=-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Are my answers right or probably i do a mistake applying the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note your normal vector is pointing upward. As per question, You need normal vector pointing downward through the cone surface. So the signs of your final answer will change otherwise it looks fine.

From cross product, you get $(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, 1)$.

Please see the third coordinate is positive that gives us upward direction but given we want downward direction, you should take the normal vector $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -1)$.

Now please do the same calculations and you will get opposite sign in both your answers.

By the way, instead of converting to polar coordinates at the time of integration, you could also parametrize the cone as below -

$T(r, \theta) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, r) \,$ $(0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi)$

So you get $T_{\theta} \times T_{r} = \, (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, -r)$

Integral becomes $\iint_D F.(T_{\theta} \times T_{r}) \, dr \, d\theta$

Comment: Then The sign varies due to the croos product vector, that is I take the normal  Vector of  the surface in opposite direction?

Comment: Yes once you do the cross product, check the normal vector. If it is pointing in the opposite direction of what you need, you reverse the sign and that will give you normal vector in the desired direction. In this case since you want downward normal vector through the surface, $k$ component of the normal vector has to be minus sign.

Comment: Thanks so much again, I finally undestand, the meaning of the flux integral, the book that I read use that formula, but it don´t tell much about geometry,

Comment: The thrid formula is just the product of my tangent vector with my vector field. You answer clarify my thoughts .I really appreciate your effort writting an answer. Thanks so much really!